# modelForm instance not coming through

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm passing an instance of a model into a modelForm, but, within the view, when I print the form, the values within the model don't show up. Also, when the form is rendered on my template, the values from the instance don't show up.

**Views.py**

```
def support_ticket_view(request, id=None): 

    id = int(id)
    instance = SupportTicket.objects.get(id=id, user=user)

    form = SupportTicketEditForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)

    context = { 
    'form': form,      
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/support_ticket_view.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SupportTicketEditForm (forms.ModelForm):    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = kwargs.pop('instance',None) 
        super(SupportTicketEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 


    class Meta:
        model = SupportTicket
        fields = (      
            'image',
            'body_question',            
            'urgency',
            'question_type',                      
            'status',
        )    

        widgets = {
            'image': ImageThumbnailFileInput
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class SupportTicket(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
   question = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

Comment: But your instance only contains `'user'` and `'question'`, whereas your form seems to have `'image'`, `'body_question'`, `'urgency'`, etc.

Comment: And why are you popping the instance from the kwargs in `__init__`? In fact, why are you defining `__init__` at all?

Comment: HI Daniel, you're correct. I've removed def init and it now works :) Thanks again. Always appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the following:

```
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = kwargs.pop('instance',None) 
        super(SupportTicketEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks Daniel Roseman!